# adding a node in Multi Level Doubly link list in c

Tags: c++, c, data-structures

I am creating a multilevel doubly link list, I am performing the adding nodes operation in it.  I'm confused because according to my logic code mentioned below it should print the value, but it is not printing.  The output is not wrong but maybe I'm doing something wrong which could affect while flatten that list.

I have 3 levels of this list. addNode function will add at the very first level, where as addChild function will add a node anywhere in 2nd or 3rd level.

code is:

```
Student* StudentList::addNode(int num)
{
    Student* node = new Student(num);
    if(head == 0) {
       head = node;
       tail = node;
    } else {
       node->prev = tail;
       tail->next = node;
       tail = tail->next;
    }

    return node;
}
```

add child:

```
Student* StudentList::addChild(Student* node1, int num)
{   
    Student* node = head;
    Student* temp;
    Student* temp1;

    // traversing the list to find exact location
    while(node != 0)
    {
        if(node->num == node1->num) {
            break;
        } else {
            temp = node->child;
            while(temp) 
            {
                if(temp->num == node1->num) {
                    node = temp;
                    break;
                } else {
                    temp1 = temp->child;
                    while(temp1) 
                    {
                        if(temp1->num == node1->num) {
                            node = temp1;
                            break;
                        } else {
                            temp1 = temp1->next;
                        }
                    }
                    temp = temp->next;
                }
            }   
            node = node->next;
        }
    }

    Student* newChild = new Student(num);
    Student* curr = node->child;
    if(curr == 0)
    {
        node->child = newChild;
    } else {
        while(curr->next)
        {
            curr = curr->next;
        }
        newChild->prev = curr;
        curr->next = newChild;
    }
    return node1;
}
```

Main Method code is:

```
StudentList* sl = new StudentList();
Student* newNode;
Student* newNode1;

newNode = sl->addNode(1);
    newNode1 = sl->addChild(newNode,11);
        sl->addChild(newNode1, 111);
        sl->addChild(newNode1, 112);
    newNode1 = sl->addChild(newNode,12);
newNode = sl->addNode(2);
    newNode1 = sl->addChild(newNode,21);
    newNode1 = sl->addChild(newNode,22);
        sl->addChild(newNode1, 221);
        sl->addChild(newNode1, 222);
        sl->addChild(newNode1, 223);
newNode = sl->addNode(3);
newNode = sl->addNode(4);
    newNode1 = sl->addChild(newNode,41);
        sl->addChild(newNode1, 411);

sl->printList();
```

and my print list code is:

```
void StudentList::printList(){
Student* curr = head;
while(curr){
    cout<< *curr <<endl;
    if(curr->child){
        Student* newCurr = curr->child;
        while(newCurr){
            cout<< "*{"<<newCurr->num <<"}"<<endl;
            if(newCurr->child){
                Student* newCurr2 = newCurr->child;
                while(newCurr2){
                        //according to my login this 3rd level childs num(id) value 
                        //should be printed used only for 2nd level according to my 
                        //logic.. where is the problem am i doing wrong any thing?
                        cout<< "**{"<<newCurr2->num <<"}"<<endl;
                        newCurr2 = newCurr2->next;
                }
            }
            newCurr = newCurr->next;
        }
    }
    curr = curr->next;
}
```

}

Kindly help me in this, thanks in advance for everyone.

Comment: Can you provide the program output please? And then describe what you don't expect in the output :)

Comment: @Jimbo This is the output of the program, i am expecting output with ** wherever 3 digit value come, according to above code '1st level 1
*{11}
*{111}
*{112}
*{12}
1st level 2
*{21}
*{22}
*{221}
*{222}
*{223}
1st level 3
1st level 4
*{41}
*{411}'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the output you've put in your comment it looks like nothing is being added at the second level. Where you're expecting nodes to be added at the second level, they are being added to the first.

I think the problem is at the bottom of the add child function:

```
Student* StudentList::addChild(Student* node1, int num)
{
    // rest of function. node1 is never modified 
    return node1;
}
```

You are always returning the node input to that function. I think in your following code

```
newNode = sl->addNode(1);
    newNode1 = sl->addChild(newNode,11);
        sl->addChild(newNode1, 111);
        sl->addChild(newNode1, 112);
```

That you will find that `newNode1 == nodeNode` and not the child node as I think you are expecting. Probably the add child function should be returning `newChild`

Comment: yeah i agree, but when i m returning newChild it give me error(Access violation reading location). what's that?

Comment: can i email you my project can u fix this for me??

Comment: The access violation means you're accessing an illegal part of memory. Probably dereferencing a NULL pointer or something like this. No. I'm not going to fix it for you. It's up to you to debug your own code chap! I'd suggest using either a debugger to step through your code and find out where the violation is or using printf statements or some other method to try and determine where your code is going wrong.

Comment: Thanks your above suggestion was right, my code is working according to logic i created, thanks.

Comment: Brill, glad you found your answer :)